# Timeout on long test case, sub string game

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem statement is as given below

> Game Rules
>
> Both players are given the same string, . Both players have to make
>   substrings using the letters of the string . Stuart has to make words
>   starting with consonants. Kevin has to make words starting with
>   vowels.  The game ends when both players have made all possible
>   substrings.
>
> Scoring A player gets +1 point for each occurrence of the substring in
>   the string .
>
> For Example: String  = BANANA Kevin's vowel beginning word = ANA Here,
>   ANA occurs twice in BANANA. Hence, Kevin will get 2 Points.
>   Your task is to determine the winner of the game and their score.

Code:

```
def minion_game(string):
    kevin,stuart=0,0
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        for j in range(i,len(string)):
            if string[i:j+1][0]=='A' or string[i:j+1][0]=='E' or string[i:j+1][0]=='I' or string[i:j+1][0]=='O' or string[i:j+1][0]=='U':
                kevin=kevin+1
            else:
                stuart=stuart+1
    if kevin>stuart:
        print('Kevin',kevin)
    elif kevin<stuart:
        print('Stuart',stuart) 
    else:
        print('Draw')



s = input()
minion_game(s)
```

Input:
[Click here](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/9693/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1535831108&Signature=tgNnzNg7LVvF40KnSc1z13%2F6g0I%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Expected output:
Stuart 7501500

Output:
Terminated due to timeout

Comment: This is a hackerrank problem correct? Could you link me to the problem?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin indeed, here is the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem

Comment: I remember solving this one, hopefully my old solution gives you some insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was my old solution to the problem

```
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = {'A','E','I','O','U'}
    kevin = 0
    stuart = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] in vowels:
            kevin += len(string) - i
        else:
            stuart += len(string) - i

    if kevin == stuart:
        print("Draw")
    elif kevin > stuart:
        print("Kevin " + str(kevin))
    else:
        print("Stuart " + str(stuart))
```

The trick is to realize you don't need to try every combination. Once you see the vowel or consonant you can be sure that there is the length of the current string sub strings left, so you can just add that many points

So for example, given the word Banana, we see a B and we immediately know that {B, BA, BAN, BANA, BANAN, BANANA} are all going to give points to Stuart. No need to keep checking

Comment: Clever to run the for loop lesser number of times like that! Thank you!

Comment: @Srinabh. Accept the answer when it answers your question. I tried its working properly

Answer (score 0):

def minion_game(string):

```
c=0
c1=0
v=('A','E','I','O','U')
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    sa=""
    if string[i] not in v:
        sa=sa+string[i]
        c=c+1
        for j in range(i,len(string)-1):
            sa=sa+string[i+1]
            c=c+1
            i=i+1
    else:
        sa=sa+string[i]
        c1=c1+1
        for j in range(i,len(string)-1):
            sa=sa+string[i+1]
            c1=c1+1
            i=i+1
if(c>c1):
    print('Stuart '+str(c))
elif(c1>c):
    print('Kevin '+str(c1))
elif(c1==c):
    print('Draw')
```